# How do I retrieve the jsessionid from URL in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, session, sessionid, jsessionid

I know how to pass the jsessionid to the URL.  I encode the url, which will look like this:

> mysite.com;jsessionid=0123456789ABCDEF (http)

Does there exist a built-in method to retrieve the jsessionid from the URL, using Java?  I found this method in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isRequestedSessionIdFromURL%28%29), isRequestedSessionIdFromURL, but it doesn't help me actually retrieve the value.  Do I have to build my own retrieval method?

Thank you.

Comment: In Servlet (or) Plain java class?

Comment: Why do you want it? It's rare you'd ever need to touch it manually.

Comment: It could be in a servlet or plain java class.  I just want to know how can I read it.  I.e., can I still perform request.getSession(false).getId()?

Answer (score 10):

JSP has an implicit `session` object, similar the `request` object. It is an instance of `java.servlet.http.HttpSession`, which has the method `getId()`.

So, you should be able to just do `session.getId()` in your JSP page.

Comment: Okay, yes, that's exactly what I was looking to see if I can still do.  Thank you.  I thought that passing jsessionid to the URL makes it part of the querystring.

Answer (score 1):

Cookieless sessions are achieved in Java by appending a string of the format `;jsessionid=SESSION_IDENTIFIER` to the end of a URL. To do this, all links emitted by your website need to be passed through either HttpServletRequest.encodeURL(), either directly or through mechanisms such as the JSTL  tag. Failure to do this for even a single link can result in your users losing their session forever.

Answer (score 0):

session.getId() should be able to get you the session id. WLS would be doing the actual parsing of the URl to retrieve the session id once it identifies that the session id is not stored in the cookie or in hidden form fields. The sequence usually is Cookie - URL - Hidden Form Fields.